# How to setup a nested dataview

Tags: extjs, nested, dataview

I have an (outer-)dataview (with tpl, store etc) which works fine. I can reorder the items (drag & drop) and edit the data.
Now I need to extend the functionality. Some items in the outer-dataview needs to show additional data in an inner-dataview. Items within this inner-dataview also must be reordered and edited. It is even getting more complex: also these items could have additional data to be shown insite the items etc etc.
By nesting the dataviews insite other dataview-items the user has a good presentation of the grouped data and can easily reorder the data by drag & drop.

I’m struggling what the best way is to build the nested dataviews. The best thing I came up with was to loop all nodes in the outer-dataview and create new inner-dataviews and use the renderTo-functionality of the dataview directly into the outer-dataview-items.
This works fine but each time I change data in the one of the outer-dataview items the related inner-dataviews disappear, because the dataview updates the dataview item.
It would help if I could re-insert the inner-dataview(s) again.

Does any one have a good suggestion how to realise the nested dataviews?

Arno

Comment: May you provide some fiddle sample? Which toolkit are you using: classic or modern? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved and the solution was quite simple.
After the creation of each dataview I dynamically render the inner-dataview into the items. simple...